# Unable to extract bash (Ubuntu) on windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The downloading had completed. While extracting the files it throws the error. How can I fix it?

[image: picture for error]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Ubuntu for windows does not support Other languages like Chinese. So change the default language to English and create a  windows user. Login using that user account and try to install bash again

Answer (score 0):

Make a new user account that has an english name, this should fix the issue!